# php login register error

Tags: php, authentication

I do have some code in OOP in PHP that's supposed to login/register a user, and a register function works great, but the login function doesn't work and I can't login. And I also have notices that in the array `$_SESSION` I have undefined indexes "login", "password". 
Here is the main page:

```
<?php 
require_once "libs/user_class.php";
$user = User::getObject();
$auth = $user->isAuth();
if(isset($_POST["reg"])){
    $login = $_POST["login"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $reg_success = $user->regUser($login,$password);
}

elseif (isset($_POST["auth"])){
    $login = $_POST["login"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $auth_success = $user->login($login,$password);
    if($auth_success){
        header("Location:index.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>REGISTER</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    if($auth){
        echo "Welcome".$_SESSION["login"];
    }
    else{
        echo '<h2>REGISTRATION</h2>
    <form action="index.php" method = "post" name="reg">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Log in</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name = "login" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name = "password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "2">
                    <input type="submit" name="reg" value = "register" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <h2>LOGIN</h2>
    <form action="index.php" method = "post" name="auth">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Log in</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name = "login" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name = "password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "2">
                    <input type="submit" name="auth" value = "authorize" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>';
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the user_class.php:

```
<?php 
class User{
private $db;
private static $user = null;
private function __construct(){
    $this->db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "temp");
    $this->db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}

public static function getObject(){
    if(self::$user === null) self::$user = new User();
    return self::$user;
}

public function regUser($login, $password){
    if($login == "")return false;
    if($password == "")return false;
    $password = md5($password);
    return $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`) VALUES  ('$login','$password')");
}

private function checkUser($login, $password){
    $result_set = $this->db->query("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE  `login` = '$login'");
    $user = $result_set->fetch_assoc();
    $result_set->close();
    if(!$user) return false;
    return $user["password"] === $password; 
}

public function isAuth(){
    session_start();
    $login = $_SESSION["login"];
    $password = $_SESSION["password"];
    return $this->checkUser($login,$password);
}

public function login($login, $password){
    if($this->checkUser($login, $password)){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["login"] = $login;
        $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

public function __destruct(){
    if ($this->db) $this->db->close();
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you called [`session_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) somewhere before you use `$_SESSION`?

Comment: the session is started in isAuth function

Answer (score 1):

In your database, you are storing the password field with md5 encryption. So, while checking username and password in your login and checkuser function, you nee to check password as md5($password).

Also, I wonder why you have kept the form name and submit button name same.